Source of Daat Zkenim - Parashat Balak
In Parashat Balak 22:10 the verse says,

וַיֹּ֥אמֶר בִּלְעָ֖ם אֶל־הָאֱלֹהִ֑ים בָּלָ֧ק בֶּן־צִפֹּ֛ר מֶ֥לֶךְ
מוֹאָ֖ב שָׁלַ֥ח אֵלָֽי׃
Balaam said to God, “Balak son of Zippor, king of Moab, sent me this
message:

On this verse the Daat Zkenim says that this is one of three places where a person did not respond properly to Hashem (Kayin and Chizkiyahu being the others - and he notes that really Adam harishon should also be in the list instead of Chizkiyahu…)
What is the original source that mentions that there were three people who did not respond properly to Hashem?
Thanks

Bamidbar Rabbah 20:6:

Rabbi Abba bar Kahana said: This is one of three people whom the Holy One blessed be He examined but found them to be a jug of urine. They are Cain, Hezekiah, and Bilam...

